# Long Running task in android

Tags: android

I want to do long running task, But if I use Activity or Service then it gives Timeout

exception, and if I use **doInBackground(Context... params)** which uses **AsyncTask**  class

But i want to do syncronse task

plz help if there is any other better alternate for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this on the UI thread.

Your options:

- **Good** - use `AsyncTask`
- **Not as good** - use `Thread`

Perhaps you could explain why you need to do this synchronously and then we can help talk you off the ledge.